# Python force regex to fail in certain conditions

Tags: regex, python-3.9

In python3 (3.9.6), using regex 2.5.91 module.

Given these lines in a file:

```
1. <span>abc.</span>
2. <span>bcd</span>
3. <span>xyz.</span>
4. <span class="good">abc</span>
5. <span class="good">abc.</span>
6. <span class="good">xyz.</span>
7. <span id="whatever">def.</span>
8. <span id="whatever">xyz.</span>
9. <span class="good" id="whatever">ghi.</span>
10. <span class="bad" id="whatever">jkl.</span>
11. <span id="whatever" class="good">abc.</span>
```

I'm trying to create a regex that will:

1. Refuse to match any line with a class, with no period at the end of the text, or with "xyz." in the text. This means that only lines 1 and 7 should be matched.
2. For the valid lines, capture the (id="whatever") if there is one, and the text in the span.

This isn't processed a line at a time; the entire file is read into a variable, and a regex.sub() is run to do a replacement on everything at once, using the capture groups. (Changing that is outside the scope of the question.) So, the regex has to fail on the "bad" lines so they're not processed by the sub.

I was able to successfully use *SKIP and *FAIL to make it fail if it found a class and capture the id if it was present, but then things fell apart when I tried to do the same if it found "xyz." in the text. IOW, this worked on the good lines and excluded the ones with a class.

```
newtext = regex.sub(r"""<span(?:(?:.*? class=".*?"(*SKIP)(*FAIL))?|( id="[a-z]+?")?)>([a-z]+\.)</span>""",r"""<span class="other"\1>\2</span>""", text)
```

When I tried to add another "|" in the text portion to fail if it found "xyz.", it caused the whole thing to *always* fail, not just when xyz. was found. IOW, this doesn't work at all, with or without a ? after the first group in the text portion between the tags.

```
newtext = regex.sub(r"""<span(?:(?:.*? class=".*?"(*SKIP)(*FAIL))?|( id="[a-z]+?")?)>(?:(?:xyz\.(*SKIP)(*FAIL))|([a-z]+\.))</span>""",r"""<span class="other"\1>\2</span>""", text)
```

I'm admittedly weak on *SKIP/*FAIL, but I thought when I got the first one working I might understand enough to make it work, but the second one proved me wrong.

So, is it possible in a single regex.sub as above to accomplish the goal, i.e. skip the lines that should be skipped, and add a class (in front of the id, if present) to the lines that aren't? (I know I'm not doing anything with the text capture group right now, but I will, it's just not relevant to this problem.)

Comment: Voting down with no comment gives the questioner no way to correct whatever problem was perceived, either on this or future questions. And the close vote was for "asks multiple questions," but I only asked one question, so I don't understand that one, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern: `^(?!<span[^<>]*class=)(?=<span(.*)>([^<>]*\.))(?!<span.*>xyz\.</span>).*$`

See Regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xJJqvQ/1)

Code:

```
import re

pattern = "^(?!<span[^<>]*class=)(?=<span(.*)>([^<>]*\.))(?!<span.*>xyz\.</span>).*$"
text = """
<span>abc.</span>
<span>bcd</span>
<span>xyz.</span>
<span class="good">abc</span>
<span class="good">abc.</span>
<span class="good">xyz.</span>
<span id="whatever">def.</span>
<span id="whatever">xyz.</span>
<span class="good" id="whatever">ghi.</span>
<span class="bad" id="whatever">jkl.</span>
<span id="whatever" class="good">abc.</span>
"""
print(re.sub(pattern, "<span class=\"other\"\\1>\\2</span>", text, 0, re.MULTILINE))
```

output:

```
<span class="other">abc.</span>
<span>bcd</span>
<span>xyz.</span>
<span class="good">abc</span>
<span class="good">abc.</span>xyz.
<span class="good">xyz.</span>
<span class="other" id="whatever">def.</span>
<span id="whatever">xyz.</span>
<span class="good" id="whatever">ghi.</span>
<span class="bad" id="whatever">jkl.</span>
<span id="whatever" class="good">abc.</span>
```

Comment: Interesting, but it 1) it doesn't guarantee that class= is found in the <span> (i.e. it fails if it's in the text), 2) doesn't guarantee that xyz. is in the text (e.g. adding xyz. after the </span> on line 6 causes it to fail when it shouldn't, and 3) doesn't capture the groups necessary for the sub to work.

Comment: Which part do you want to capture?

Comment: I specified it in the question, #2 below the example lines of text.

Comment: I'm going to vote for this, for although you interpreted the lines a little too literally (a <span> is not always going to be at the beginning of a line), that's at least partially my fault for trying to simply my data for the question perhaps a little too much, plus you gave me some ideas of different ways to attack the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is the file proper HTML? Maybe try [`html.parser.HTMLParser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html#html.parser.HTMLParser) like so:

```py
from html import parser
from io import IOBase

class MyParser(parser.HTMLParser):
    """collects acceptable line-numbers/line-data"""
    
    def __init__(self, obj):
        """construct self, feed self"""
        super().__init__()
        self.data = list()
        if isinstance(obj, IOBase):
            line = obj.readline() # might need .decode("latin-1")
            while line is not "":
                self.feed(line)
                line = fp.readline() # .decode("latin-1")
            self.close()
        elif isinstance(obj, str):
            self.feed(obj)

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        """accept/reject tags"""
        attrs = dict(attrs)
        if tag == "span" and "class" not in attrs:
            data = self.get_starttag_text()
            if data.endswith(".") and "xyz." not in data:
                self.data.append((attrs.get("id"), data))


# usage would be like:
good_tags = MyParser(html_string) # a string or a file
for tag_id, text in good_tags.data:
    print(tag_id, text)
```

This approach has the benefit of not needing complicated REs, and can even be altered to utilize simple string methods like `endswith` (or more atomic/simpler REs if you like). The constructor is written out to accept file pointer, or string objects. When the file contents are fed in, the `handle_starttag` method is called by the instance each time a tag is encountered, and the logic in it is executed. At the end of the file or string, all the desired data should be available in the `data` attribute.

Comment: Well, as I said, there is a ton of other stuff going on, this particular replacement is just one of a hundred or more. But, I believe xpath is used elsewhere, so that's a possibility, and would be similar to your approach, so I may look into that as well.